# Visual basic date object parsing from string with indexing

Tags: vba, excel, date

I would like to ask if in VBA there is a built in function which will parse a date object from a string based on a specified format.

For example:

```
dateString = "24-4-12"
VBADateFunc(dateString, "dd-m-yy")
```

to return a date object interpreting the dateString string by the provided format.

I will appretiate your ideas on this.

Thank you

Comment: you can use `format(cdate("4-24-12"),"dd-m-yy")` but the date string must be in american English format `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: A date isn't an *object* in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim dtMyDate    As Date

    dtMyDate = Format("24-4-12", "dd-mm-yy")

    Debug.Print dtMyDate
    Debug.Print Format(dtMyDate, "yyyy")
    Debug.Print Format(dtMyDate, "dd-mmm-yy")

    'For Non-Europeans:
    dtMyDate = Format(DateSerial(2012, 4, 24), "dd-mm-yy")
    Debug.Print dtMyDate
    Debug.Print Format(dtMyDate, "yyyy")
    Debug.Print Format(dtMyDate, "dd-mmm-yy")

End Sub
```

From the comments - in general, the date is a long value in MS Excel and VBA. Today's date can be seen like this in the immediate window:

```
?clng(now)
 42935
```

If you want to do further something with the 42935 value, you may go like this:

```
?Format(42934,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Note: Today is 42934 for all those, who have `ActiveWorkbook.Date1904 = False`. For those, who are starting the calendar with `1904`, today is `42935-4*365-1`

Comment: Um... since the date as not in an american English format the results are `12/4/2024  
2024
04-Dec-24`

Comment: Even if you are European, as I understand it, vba requires the dates to be in American English format.  It is independent of the local settings.  I know this is correct for formulas, I assume it is for dates also.  But as I said I may be wrong.

Comment: @ScottCraner - the date is a long value. Check like this - `?clng(date())` in the immediate window. Independent on your settings, it would give 42934, which is the 42934. day from January 1900 (or January 1904), depending on your settings.

Comment: I understand how it works and what it is.  My question is on a computer that is using European dates, does the date need to match American English format like formulas do?  IE even if your local settings require `;` in formulas on the worksheet, you need to use `,` when adding the formula via `Range.Formula`.

Comment: @ScottCraner - in my Excel, when I try to obtain the last day of the year through a formula `=DATUM(2017;12;31)` Excel gives me this - `31.12.2017`. And it is based on my `Regional Settings`. And if I select it and write `?Selection.Formula`, I get `=DATE(2017,12,31)`

Comment: See here: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson14.htm  If the string can be converted to `mm-dd-yyyy` it will be, regardless of the local settings.  If some one in europe where to `Clng("4/5/2017")` then would get the value  for the 5th of April and not the 4th of May.  The DateSerial is the only method that ensures proper conversions.

Comment: Use `arr = Split("24-4-12", "-")` into array and then `DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))`, i.e. shuffle those as needed. I do not know if regular date related functionality in VBA respects the locale setting - try and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your suggestions. I am now checking them up and adapting to my code. The reason for asking at first place was the fact that Excel gets the date presentation settings from Windows and dates in the format 24-Apr-16 are parsed wrongly when windows is set to use ` yy-mm-dd` . So I am seeking for a robust way to read the date.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing my own function to scan a date. Leaving out error handling:

```
Function ScanDate(s As String, Optional order As String = "DMY", Optional separator As String = "-") As Date

    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(s, separator)
    Dim day As Long, month As Long, year As Long
    day = parts(InStr(order, "D") - 1)
    month = parts(InStr(order, "M") - 1)
    year = parts(InStr(order, "Y") - 1)

    ScanDate = DateSerial(year, month, day)

End Function
```